# Cannot copy file to Docker container via Spotify Docker Client

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, spotify, spotify-docker-client

I want to copy file to the not running container via Docker Client by [Spotify](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/) -

File is created like -

```
File.createTempFile("olb-", "-temp").deleteOnExit().writeText("some text")
```

When I try:

```
client.copyToContainer(inputFileProvider.createFile(task.dataToInsert).toPath(), containerId, "/app/asd.json")
```

I get:

```
Either container 1adbf9c1ee511272bec78a46be08bf9299c317b11cdb176eed986640ac86a38c or path /app/my_json.json not found.
```

Well, ok - I create this file while building image with `RUN touch /app/my_json.json`
Next run:

```
client.copyToContainer(inputFileProvider.createFile(task.dataToInsert).toPath(), containerId, "/app/my_json.json")
```

Resulted in

```
{"message":"extraction point is not a directory"}
```

Ok... I tried directory

```
copyToContainer(inputFileProvider.createFile(task.dataToInsert).toPath(), containerId, "/app/")
```

Result:

```
{"message":"Error processing tar file(exit status 1): cannot overwrite directory \"/\" with non-directory \"/\""}
```

Same for `"/app"`

Any ideas how to copy file into docker container via Java client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I must create whole new folder, then single file in it and copy that folder.

```
val dir = Files.createTempDirectory("tem-folder-")
Files.createFile(dir.resolve("filename")).toFile().writeText("data to write")

val toBeCopied = dir.toFile()

cliend.copyToContainer(toBeCopied.toPath(), "containerId", "targetPath")
```